# Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... Fatal error: Cannot redeclare preprocessGrammar()

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, test-coverage

I have had the error: **Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... Fatal error: Cannot redeclare preprocessGrammar() (previously declared in /app/vendor/nikic/php-parser/grammar/phpyLang.php:22) in /app/vendor/nikic/php-parser/grammar/phpyLang.php on line 22**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.5/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         cacheResultFile=".phpunit.cache/test-results">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">.</directory>
        </include>
        <report>
            <clover outputFile="phpunit.coverage.xml"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>

    <logging>
        <junit outputFile="phpunit.report.xml"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

I had this error only when I used test coverage.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was here:

```xml
<include>
    <directory suffix=".php">.</directory>
</include>
```

I wanted to cover all the files, they were in `src` and in the root directory of the project.

In the root directory were `tests` and they were included for the test coverage. It made a recursive call.

For solving this problem I set concrete directory (`src`) and files (`.php-cs-fixer.`). I have used this directives:

```xml
<include>
    <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    <directory prefix=".php-cs-fixer.">.</directory>
</include>
```

I also could use `<file>`, but I had several files and using `directory` for me more useful. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-file-element

The `<exclude>` directive didn't for me.

My finally configuration.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.5/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         cacheResultFile=".phpunit.cache/test-results">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            <directory prefix=".php-cs-fixer.">.</directory>
        </include>
        <report>
            <clover outputFile="phpunit.coverage.xml"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>

    <logging>
        <junit outputFile="phpunit.report.xml"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```